# Import wolfssf into Wiznet W5100S SDK

Tags: cmake, sdk, raspberry-pi-pico, wolfssl

I have problem with importing cryptographic library wolfssl into SDK for board Wiznet W5100S (use chip RP2040, similar to raspberry-pi-pico and also contains Ethernet port). I want to import wolfssl into my SDK and compile it with CMake. I tried several metrods but they didn't work. How can I do that?

PS: I`am beginner with CMake 
**Links:**

- SDK: https://github.com/Wiznet/RP2040-HAT-C/tree/main
- wolfssl library: https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfssl